# Selenium Session not created for JAVA in eclipse on ARCH LINUX

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, automation, arch

I use arch linux a window is appeared and disappeared with a second and its shows the error like

"**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 120.0.6099.109 with binary path /usr/lib/chromium/chromium** "

How to solve this by code and in case how to reduce the version